# mysql select values as column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

It's hard to give a title to this question but much easier to understand by showing the structure of tables:

There are 2 tables below:

Table A:

| idA(int) | label(json) |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | [1, 3] |
| 1002 | [3, 2] |

Table B:

| idB(int) | name(string) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple |
| 2 | orange |
| 3 | strawberry |
| ... | ... |

Require outputs:

| idA | apple | orange | strawberry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1002 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

how to use mysql query to get this ?

Comment: You need to join using `JSON_SEARCH`, and then pivot the results. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns for how to pivot

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 
    a.idA,
    SUM(CASE b.name WHEN 'apple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  apple,
    SUM(CASE b.name WHEN 'orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  orange,
    SUM(CASE b.name WHEN 'strawberry' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  strawberry
from a 
left join b on  FIND_IN_SET(b.idB,a.label)
group by    a.idA
```

- My mysql version is low and there is no json type. I hope this will help you!

Comment: Nice answer, but usually is better to not provide "only code" answers and trying to explain what it does

Comment: If the version of MySQL is important, you can check with `select @@version` and put the version here. Why do you mention JSON type? Is `a.label` a stringified JSON? Also, the `JOIN ON` condition `FIND_IN_SET(b.idB,a.label)` is probably not what you want. This must be a condition for the engine to know when to match rows from both tables e.g. `ON a.idA = b.idB`. It would be helpful if you add examples of the content for tables `a` & `b` and what results you expect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's good when number of objects are limited but it's not, any way to improve ?

Answer (score -1):

Try selecting from both tables together since you can't join them - `select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1, table2 t2`

Comment: This is just a full cross product, they want a pivot